# multiple secondary index for dynamoDB query

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I'm looking to request my DynamoDB table using to secondary-index I've made in my query.

As of now for a single secondary-index I'm doing :

```
response = dynamodb.Table('TABLE').query(
    IndexName='permaname-index',
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('permaname').eq(permaname)
)
```

I would build my KeyConditionExpression like this :

```
KeyConditionExpression=Key('permaname').eq(permaname) & Key('source').eq(source)
```

I've read again and again this doc but I can not figure out how to do:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/amazondynamodb/latest/gettingstartedguide/GettingStarted.Python.04.html

and

https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: You mean using multiple secondary index on single query param?

Comment: yes @notionquest

Answer (score 6):

The DynamoDB Query (i.e. Query API params) can get data from single resource at a time (i.e. a table or GSI). In other words, you can't retrieve data from multiple tables or GSI in a single Query param. DynamoDB Query can refer to only one resource at a time.

Unlike, RDBMS which can refer to multiple tables, DynamoDB can't refer to multiple tables or GSI at a same time (i.e. in a single Query).

Because of this reason, DynamoDB has a feature to include all the attributes in main table in GSI. You can use `ProjectionType` to include all the attributes in a table onto GSI while creating the GSI for the table.

> ProjectionType: ALL

**Sample GSI query:-**

```
response = table.query(
    IndexName='Movies_Gsi',
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('title').eq('Movie with nested map') & Key('yearkey').eq(2017)
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm not sur to understand how to build my request. Could you please show me an exemple using my case  @notionquest ?

Comment: Both are key attributes

Comment: I have updated the sample GSI query which works fine for me. If something is not working for you, please add the error message on OP.